# ORDER BY soundex with WHERE (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like, soundex

Query code:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
OR SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T230%'
OR SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T23%'
```

I want to show first the results matched with `WHERE name LIKE '%test%'` and after `SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T230%'` and the lasts rows is the result of `SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T23%'`

Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean expressions in `order by`.  The "true" is treated as "1" and false as "0".  So:

```
ORDER BY (name LIKE '%test%') DESC,
         (SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T23%') DESC,
         (SOUNDEX(name) LIKE 'T230%') DESC
```